# Does coffee make you poop?

Tags: health

what would speed up bowel movements which chemical compound causes that reaction.does it triggers higher stomach acid levels?

Answer (score 2):

I found this: 
"Caffeine within coffee can act as a stimulant, which **might induce bile production that increases bowel movements**. And some artificial sweeteners, and lactose, may have a laxative effect."

From: https://iffgd.org/lower-gi-disorders/diarrhea/common-causes.html

Comment: Thankyou @Èmile

Comment: Your welcome !   @InshaDarwaish

Answer (score 0):

A Banana and a large mug of home brewed coffee is almost guaranteed to get things going.

Now I can’t back it up with science and references. But I do have years of experience